# Grub Menu Timer is not there now

Tags: grub2

I have to press enter in the grub menu! earlier the 10 second timer was there. but now, I have to press enter (no timer is there). How to repair it?

My grub file:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
# info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="5"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo BOSS`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash gfxpayload=1024x768x16 quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you actually don't really want the menu to appear each time you boot, so by following this, you can have it only show the menu on pressing shift while booting.

Open the `grub` configuration by typing:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Now, if you don't really want the grub menu even appearing without your consent, just add this line to the file:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

and then change:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT="5"
```

to:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT="0"
```

Save this file, run the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and then after a reboot you should be able to see the change.

Answer (score 3):

Install `grub-customizer` on ubuntu,through which you can set the grub timer.Run the below commands on terminal to install grub-customizer,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adabbas/1stppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

To open grub-customizer,

```
sudo grub-customizer
```

[image]

**Advanced Settings** would be under General Settings tab. After changing the GRUB_TIMEOUT value, please don't forget to save it.

Answer (score 0):

This nag fail with **GRUB's timeout** is appearing on Ubuntu since v10.

Even when the solution of @AvinashRaj is fine because it offers a specialised software that brings several useful configuration features, working as a computer scientist, I have deployed Ubuntu (and some others Debian-based distros) in multiple computers during the last few years, and this other method, just based on **changing a parameter** of the GRUB's configuration file, is my preferred one to solve this issue:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

and then I **add this line** somewhere:

```
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=10
```

save the results, and then:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Easy and fast.

According to GRUB documentation:

> This option should be set on headless and appliance systems where
>   access to a console is restricted or limited.

But I am not sure why this works. It seems some kind of *emergency escape pod* that will always work X-D .